# Harmonic oscillator with random forcing term

Tags: probability, physics, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm stuck on the following problem:
a harmonic oscillator with forcing term is described by the following equation:

$$\ddot x(t)+\omega^2 x(t)=A(t)\cos(\omega t)$$
where $A(t)$ is a random function with pdf:

$$pdf [A(t)]=\dfrac{k}{\lambda}\left(\dfrac{t}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}\exp\left(-\dfrac{t}{\lambda}\right)^k$$

with $k\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\gt 0$, $\lambda\gt 0$ (Weibull distribution pdf).
Is it still possible to speak of forced oscillation?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "random function with pdf"? A density is usually given as $P(A(t)=a)=...$ in the discrete case or $p^A(a)=...$ in the continuous case? What time regularity does $A$ have? Or is the formula correct as stated, without any randomness and stochastics?

Comment: @LutzLehmann: I corrected the post